# Different gaps using math mode in tabular

Tags: tables, math-mode, gap

See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|D{5cm}|}
\hline
$\{x\in \mathbb{Q} \, | \, 3{,}8<x<4 \}$\\\hline
$4x+2<5$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\[12pt]
$\{x\in \mathbb{Q} \,|\, 3{,}8<x<4 \}$\\[4pt]
$4x+2<5$
\end{document}
```

[image]


As you can see, the gap between the relation sign and the number is increased when I use the new defined columntype (which I need for different reasons). If I use the common `p{...}` columntype, the gap isn't increased. So, why is the gap increased and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I think you should use a dot for decimals in the *input*, e.g., `3.8`, and then deciding which *output* you want; that way you leave `.` for decimals, and `,` for commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

`\Centering` unlike the standard `\centering` uses a finite amount of stretch on the left and right sides. This means that the glue stretching is balanced with interword  and math glue stretching.

There are various ways of forcing the math to be set to natural width, for example as here adding an extra `{}` group as shown in the second table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|D{5cm}|}
\hline
$\{x\in \mathbb{Q} \, | \, 3{,}8<x<4 \}$\\\hline
$4x+2<5$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{|D{5cm}|}
\hline
${\{x\in \mathbb{Q} \, | \, 3{,}8<x<4 \}}$\\\hline
${4x+2<5}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}


$\{x\in \mathbb{Q} \,|\, 3{,}8<x<4 \}$\\[4pt]
$4x+2<5$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you name another way of forcing the math to bet set to natural width?

Comment: @Gotti91 you could use `\centering` you could use `\mbox{$...$}`outside the math instead of `{}` inside the math, you could locally (in your definition of the D column) reset `\thinmuskip`, `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip` to be fixed lengths without plus/minus components or ...